# $ is not defined in callback function

Tags: jquery

I get

> $ is not defined

when I try to use `$` in a success callback of `$.get(...)` I get the above error in firebug

How come?

jQuery is loaded according to the net tab in firebug (200 OK).
jQuery is loaded first (my script is the only other script).
Calling `$.get(...)` works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        $.get("response.xml", function (data) {
            var $cases = $(data).find('case');
        }, "xml");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Try logging what `data` contains to the console.

Comment: -1: Unanswerable without a testcase. This is textbook code.

Comment: Your code [works](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/feNv8/) in Firefox 3.6, 4, and 7; Chrome 16; and IE 9.  You have something else going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solved

**Arghh!** This was my first shot at **jQuery** and the first example I found of adding a click handler used the `<a>` tag which was used as `<a href="">this is a link</a>`, which causes a page to load, in this case a page reload, thereby corrupting **$**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something overrides the `$` variable.

Safe way to write your script:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
       $("a").click(function(){
          $.get("response.xml", function(data){
             var $cases = $(data).find('case');
             }, "xml"
          );
       });
    });
)(jQuery);
```

Comment: No. Then the outermost occurrence of `$` would have failed first. If anything you would wrap the callback contents, but even there I doubt that's the issue.

Comment: The OP said that the ajax call is being made, just when it gets to the callback it has the error...